# FlatButton with Text ellipsis overflowed

Tags: flutter, layout, flutter-layout, ellipsis

I try to use an ellipsis when the Text of a FlatButton overflows.

It works with a normal FlatButton but not with a FlatButton.icon. I would appreciate an explanation.

```
void main() => runApp(Test());

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        // bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(child: widgetOk()),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(child: widgetNotOk()),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget widgetOk() {
  return Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Flexible(
        child: FlatButton(
          child: Text('0123456789' * 10, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
      Flexible(
        child: FlatButton(
          child: Text('0123456789' * 10, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}

Widget widgetNotOk() {
  return Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Flexible(
        child: FlatButton.icon(
          icon: Icon(Icons.bug_report),
          label: Text('0123456789' * 10, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
      Flexible(
        child: FlatButton.icon(
          icon: Icon(Icons.bug_report),
          label: Text('0123456789' * 10, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap `label` with `Flexible` to see the `ellipsis` take effect.

Working code below:

```
Flexible(
        child: FlatButton.icon(
          icon: Icon(Icons.bug_report),
          label: Flexible(
              child: Text('0123456789' * 10, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis)),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
      Flexible(
        child: FlatButton.icon(
          icon: Icon(Icons.bug_report),
          label: Flexible(
            child: Text('0123456789' * 10, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's working. However I don't understand why 2 Flexibles are needed for each Text. Would you have an explanation?

Comment: The outer `Flexible` is to tell `Row` to take only available space for all its children. Since one of its children is `FlatButton.icon` that itself is a combination of 2 widgets, `Text` and `icon`. According to official documentation, the icon and text are padded by 12 pixels at the start and 16 at the end and 8 pixels of gap between them. So in order for larger text to render properly and accomodate `icon` at the same time, `Flexible` is used.  Hope this helps.